# Why can an XML element of type xsd:anyURI contain a non-URI string?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

This is currently what I have for my `video` element that can only contain an URI.

```
<xs:element name="video">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:anyURI"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

.. But for some reason I am still able to put garbage content inside of video element and it does not throw an error.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your declaration to merely,

```
<xs:element name="video" type="xs:anyURI"/>
```

but you still won't get a strict interpretation of what constitutes a URI because only ***modest obligations*** are imposed on minimally conforming processors with respect to URI syntax rules:

> ### [3.2.17 anyURI](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#anyURI)
>
> [...]
>   **Note:**  Each URI scheme imposes specialized syntax rules for URIs in
>   that scheme, including restrictions on the syntax of allowed fragment
>   identifiers. Because it is impractical for processors to check that a
>   value is a context-appropriate URI reference, this specification
>   follows the lead of [[RFC 2396](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#RFC2396)] (as amended by [[RFC 2732](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#RFC2732)]) in this
>   matter: such rules and restrictions are not part of type validity and
>   are not checked by [·minimally conforming·](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-minimally-conforming) processors. Thus in practice
>   the above definition imposes only very modest obligations on
>   [·minimally conforming·](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-minimally-conforming) processors.